# Points in polygon

Tags: qgis

I want to count the number of benches in cementeries in a city. I am using OSM data and tried Vector Analysis Count Points in Polygon but it does not seem to get me result. I have put Cementery as Polygon and Benches as Points and did not put weight of class field.

Comment: Please specify what you mean when you write "does not seem to get me result". Is there no output? Are there no changes to the output? Do you get an error message?

Comment: There are changes in terms of new field called Numpoint and all shows yero. Is there a way of getting the amount of benches in all polygons specifically and to do it all at once or I would need to do each separately?

Comment: What version of QGIS? In older versions, most tools required that all input layers be in the same projection. But in QGIS 3.4 the  `count points in polygons` tool seems to work when the input layers are in different projections.

Comment: Make sure the polygon layer doesn't have any invalid geometry. Make sure the point layer is single points, not multipoints.

Comment: The version is 3.8 and as for invalid geometry, it does show there are a lot of points with invalid geometry. How do I fix that?